# Webpack - Use variable to compile

Tags: laravel, webpack

I'm using Laravel & Webpack to compile CSS for 4 different themes. But each time I only want to compile the one theme.

I am storing in my Database a template_home variable. I don't mind putting this var in my .env file either..

Ideally I'd like to then use that variable to compile one of the 4 mixes.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you not to have 4 different css files for 4 different themes. Use css variables and just change only them when you want to implement new theme. It is much better UX (no additional requests to server => faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible with the `dotenv` npm package.

1. First install the package with npm: `npm install dotenv --save-dev`.
2. Then add the template key to the `.env`-file:

```
...
THEME_KEY=test_01
...
```

3. To access and use the variable you need to edit your `webpack.mix.js`-file:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/' + process.env.THEME_KEY + '.scss', 'css');
```

Hope this helps!